# jQuery custom checkbox - graphic update not working

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Trying to set a custom checkbox value when the form loads. Debug tells me the checkbox reflects the value loaded from a source but the custom graphic won't update.

In my form I have

```
<input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="uitem_autorenew" id="uitem_autorenew" />
```

Style I have:

```
    .checkbox {
        display: none;
    }

    .toggle {
        background: url("toggle.png") bottom left;
        display: block;
        width: 70px;
        height: 22px;
    }

    .toggle.checked {
        background-position: top left;
    }
```

Code includes the following

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.checkbox').after(function() {
            if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
                return "<a href='#' class='toggle checked' ref='" + $(this).attr("id") + "'></a>";
            } else {
                return "<a href='#' class='toggle' ref='" + $(this).attr("id") + "'></a>";
            }

        });
```

...into the dialog which has an open event... definitely setting the check or uncheck feature according to the data

```
                var ar=$(this).data('renew');
                console.log("Value of ar = " + ar);  // which is Y

                if (ar =="Y"){
                    $("#uitem_autorenew").prop('checked',true);  // tried this 
                    $("#uitem_autorenew").toggleClass("checked");   //tried this too


                }

                console.log ("Is checkbox checked?");
                console.log ($("#uitem_autorenew").prop('checked'));   // yes it is but the graphic has not toggled. Top left of toggle.png is has word "YES"
```

I'm just wondering what I am missing in the case that the style has not changed.
Any clues welcomed and thanks in advance.
Kevin

Answer (score 0):

You toggle the "checked" class on the checkbox element, but you want to change it for your dynamically created a-tag. so try changing

```
$("#uitem_autorenew").toggleClass("checked");
```

to

```
$(".toggle").toggleClass("checked");
```